# Need some help with approacing on how to calculate the following expecatation

Tags: probability

I cant solve this problem. though maybe I could get some help with how to approach question like that.

Let $\{X_1,X_2,...\}$ a series of i.i.d random variables.
Let N be the maximum length of the monotonicly decreasing intevral from the start of the series.

for example : $N=3$ for $\{5,2,1,6,7, \dots\}$ and $N=1$ for $\{2,4,5, \dots\}$

Now I need to find $E(N)$ , I've tried using $\sum P(N>n)$=$\sum (1-P(N\leq n) )$ but I think that I can't get the correct probability function.

The answer is $e-1$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What assumptions do you have on your distribution for your i.i.d. variables, and how do you define decreasing? If your variables are always equal to a fixed value with probability 1, and you define decreasing to be weakly decreasing, then for an infinite sequence of i.i.d. draws you would have $E(N) = \infty$. Or if you defined decreasing to be strictly decreasing you would have $E(N) = 1$.

Comment: No assumptions. I think that if they are all i.i.d then the chance of (xi>xj)=1/2 ?

Comment: No like I said, if you take a delta distribution then $E(N) = 1$ or $E(N) = \infty$ depending on how you define decreasing. I.e. in that case you would have $P(x_i > x_j) = 0$ always. So there must be some assumptions on your distribution, e.g. maybe it is given by a continuous finite-valued density on the real line, or continuous distribution function?

Comment: I wasnt given any, but you do have a point. thanks!!! it is a question from an old test (I wonder if any one came though of that during the test...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume that our random variables have **continuous** distribution. More specifically, we need to assume that if $i\ne j$, then with probability $1$ we have $X_i\ne X_j$.

The probability that $N\ge n$ is the probability that the first $n$ terms are in decreasing order.

By the iid condition, any of the $n!$ permutations of ordering among the first $n$ entries are equally likely. Only one is strictly decreasing.

Thus $\Pr(N\ge n)=\dfrac{1}{n!}$. This will be enough for the calculation of the expectation of $N$.

Comment: yes. that is perfect. I was trying to go and build some wierd series and combinations. but the combinatorical approach is fantastic